# Ruby on Rails: grouping blog posts by month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

Hy guys. I've created a simple blog app with the usual CRUD actions. I've also added a new action in the PostController called "archive" and an associated view. In this view I want to bring back all blog posts and group them by month, displaying them in this kind of format:

```
March
<ul>
    <li>Hello World</li>
    <li>Blah blah</li>
    <li>Nothing to see here</li>
    <li>Test post...</li>
</ul>

Febuary
<ul>
    <li>My hangover sucks</li>
    ... etc ...
```

I can't for the life of me figure out the best way to do this. Assuming the Post model has the usual `title`, `content`, `created_at` etc fields, can someone help me out with the logic/code? I'm very new to RoR so please bear with me :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

group_by is a great method:

controller:

```
def archive
  #this will return a hash in which the month names are the keys, 
  #and the values are arrays of the posts belonging to such months
  #something like: 
  #{ "February" => [#<Post 0xb5c836a0>,#<Post 0xb5443a0>],
  # 'March' => [#<Post 0x43443a0>] }
  @posts_by_month = Posts.find(:all).group_by { |post| post.created_at.strftime("%B") }
end
```

view template:

```
<% @posts_by_month.each do |monthname, posts| %>
<%= monthname %>
<ul>
   <% posts.each do |post| %>
     <li><%= post.title %></li>
   <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is more related to the OP: * You might want to group by Year-Month, because once it rolls over to the next year (say, 2010), then January's section will have both 2009's & 2010's entries in it. * You may wish to have each month's entries sorted by (day) date, to ensure the list is chronological.

Comment: Palm slap moment, I've been doing my own similar group_by functionality for displaying groups of records in my views.  Glad I discovered this.

Comment: I think the answer is slightly out of date for newer rails. I used: `@posts_by_month = Post.all.group_by { |post| post.created_at.strftime("%B") }` for rails 3.2. BUT how does this work with I18n? my yml is right but I think I must be missing something.

Comment: Thank you so much. you gave me exactly what i want.

Answer (score 7):

@Maximiliano Guzman

Good answer! Thanks for adding value to the Rails community. I'm including my original source on [How to Create a Blog Archive with Rails](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/29-create-a-blog-archive-with-rails), just in case I butcher the author's reasoning. Based on the blog post, for new developers to Rails, I'd add a couple suggestions.

First, use Active Records *Posts.all* method to return the Post result set for increased speed and interoperability. The *Posts.find(:all)* method is known to have unforeseen issues.

Finally, along the same vein, use **beginning_of_month** method from the ActiveRecord core extensions. I find **beginning_of_month** much more readable than **strftime("%B")**. Of course, the choice is yours.

Below is an example of these suggestions. Please see the original blog post for further detail:

controllers/archives_controller.rb

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all(:select => "title, id, posted_at", :order => "posted_at DESC")
    @post_months = @posts.group_by { |t| t.posted_at.beginning_of_month }
end
```

views/archives/indext.html.erb

```
<div class="archives">
    <h2>Blog Archive</h2>

    <% @post_months.sort.reverse.each do |month, posts| %>
    <h3><%=h month.strftime("%B %Y") %></h3>
    <ul>
        <% for post in posts %>
        <li><%=h link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Good luck and welcome to Rails!

Comment: @steve, How about that, does it effect any speed ? if I don't want to use ** and Just use this line? 

Post.all(:select => "title, id, posted_at", :order => "posted_at DESC")**.

**@posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').group_by { |post| post.created_at.beginning_of_month }**