# Rails output by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out the best way to display all records by date. I have a date_due column in my database that is a datetime field.

So my output would include every date for which there is an entry, like this:

> April 1, 2011
>    - Buy tickets
>    - Pickup groceries
>
> April 2, 2011
>    - Call client

I am trying to use the following method, which is not working: **find_all_by_date_due**

What's the easiest way to do this in Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Railscasts has a nice cast on group_by :

http://railscasts.com/episodes/29-group-by-month

Comment: Awesome! I was looking for a railscast on this. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Also found a nice description on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080547/ruby-on-rails-grouping-blog-posts-by-month

Answer (score 0):

You could make the dates into an association and assign it an arbitrary ID through rails.

```
class Entry 
  belongs_to :date
end

class Date
  has_many :entries
end

@entry.date.build(:date => 2011-02-01 20:23:22)

@entry.find_by_date(2)

Date.find(2).date 
=> 2011-02-01 20:23:22
```

Comment: That whole having a method "date" for class "Date" was a bad idea on my part, however, I couldn't link of a decent synonym :)